# post hook edit entity

Tags: api, hooks

We have a post hook that sends some data to an external api when a participant is created or edited.

`function kavo_civicrm_post($op, $objectName, $objectId, &$objectRef) {
  if (($op == 'create' || $op == 'edit') && $objectName == 'Participant') {`

Based on the response of that api a custom field on the response of that API a couple of custom fields on the participant should be set. This is done using the php api, but results in a loop with the post hook being called, even when following the add_callback instructions in the [post hook documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_post/).

`try {
               civicrm_api3('Kavo', 'createparticipant', ['participant_id' => $objectId]);
               $successState = CRM_Kavo_Status::KAVO_ATTENDED();
               CRM_Core_Transaction::addCallback(CRM_Core_Transaction::PHASE_POST_COMMIT, 'set_kavo_state', [$objectId, $successState]);
            } catch (CiviCRM_API3_Exception $ex) {
               $contact = $worker->getContact($participant);
               CRM_Core_Session::setStatus($ex->getMessage(), ts("Failed sending participant %1 to KAVO.", [1 => $contact['display_name']]), 'error');
               $failedState = CRM_Kavo_Status::KAVO_FAILED();
               CRM_Core_Transaction::addCallback(CRM_Core_Transaction::PHASE_POST_COMMIT, 'set_kavo_state', [$objectId, $failedState, $ex->getMessage()]);
            }`

`function set_kavo_state($participant_id, $state, $message='success'){
  $kavo_status_field = CRM_Kavo_Field::KAVO_PARTICIPANT_STATUS();
  $kavo_message_field = CRM_Kavo_Field::KAVO_PARTICIPANT_MESSAGE();
  civicrm_api3('Participant', 'create', array(
    'id' => $participant_id,
    $kavo_status_field => $state,
    $kavo_message_field => $message
  ));
}`

The kavo create_participant call does our call to the external api
 Is there another way to edit the participant being edited in a post hook?

Comment: I am not clear on what you are asking, can you give a little more detail? I think I understand (and know the problem) but I am not sure.....

Comment: In a post hook we send a request to an external api. This post hook is limited to working on particapants on edit or create. Depending on the succes of the api call I want to set a costum field on the participant. I will edit some code in the original question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The participant create in `set_kavo_state()` triggers your post hook again which then calls `set_kavo_state()` etc.  You need to determine whether the post hook is being called just to update the `$kavo_status_field` and `$kavo_message_field` fields - and therefore not set up another callback to `set_kavo_state()`.

Do you actually need to call your external API for participant edits?  If you could limit the post hook to only trigger on 'create' you would avoid the loop.

Comment: The external api needs to be called when participants are edited, and their kavo fields need to be set based on the api response.
I know the call to set the kavo fiels is the reason for getting in the loop, I was wondering wether there was a way to set them without getting back in the post hook.

Comment: I think that if you check your request in the post hook you can determine if you are coming in from the API or not?

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices:

- Use `hook_civicrm_pre` instead of `hook_civirm_post`.  This isn't ideal because it's synchronous and will slow down your writes.
- Since you're updating custom fields only, continue to use `hook_civicrm_post`, but instead of calling `Participant.create`, call `CustomValue.create`, which won't trigger the post hook a second time.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Drupal, you can use the Drupal static cache infrastructure to break the cycle. In this particular example, the static cache is only available for one page load / http request. You can set a database cache as well, see References below for detailed explanation and instructions

```
function set_kavo_state($participant_id, $state, $message='success'){
  $stop = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__);
  // could use more logic in this conditional if need be ... but at least you will know if you've come back a second time...
  if (!isset($stop)) {
    $kavo_status_field = CRM_Kavo_Field::KAVO_PARTICIPANT_STATUS();
    $kavo_message_field = CRM_Kavo_Field::KAVO_PARTICIPANT_MESSAGE();
    civicrm_api3('Participant', 'create', array(
      'id' => $participant_id,
      $kavo_status_field => $state,
      $kavo_message_field => $message
    ));
    $stop = 1;
  }
}
```

References:
[Drupal API documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static/7.x)
[A Beginner's Guide to Caching Data in Drupal 7](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/a-beginners-guide-to-caching-data-in-drupal-7)